# iOS 7: Delete button color of calendar app, how to get it?

Tags: ios, button

I've created a similar screen as the edit screen of a calendar event. Now I have the same button for deletion but in blue at the bottom of my screen. How can I get this orange/red programmatically for this button?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the color `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.945 green:0.231 blue:0.129 alpha:1.0]`. I got it with the help of a screencolor picker.